# Toast Notification not working 

Tags: windows-8, toast, microsoft-metro

Below method executes on call for set Toast, but doesnot display any Toast after time elasped. 
Is any more setting required for Windows 8 Metro app Toast notification

```
 int scheduledToastCounter = 1;

    public void Set_Future_Toast()
    {

            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

            XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            stringElements.Item(0).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Scheduled Toast"));

            DateTimeOffset displayTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3);

            ScheduledToastNotification scheduledToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(toastXml, displayTime);
            scheduledToast.Id = "Future_" + this.scheduledToastCounter++;

            ToastNotifier notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
            notifier.AddToSchedule(scheduledToast);

            int scheduledToastCount = notifier.GetScheduledToastNotifications().Count;
        }

     }
```

Comment: What's the empty `catch` block doing there? Other than hiding bugs.

Comment: @CodyGray I just blanked out exception handling here. But method executes without any exception.

Answer (score 14):

You should set toast capable to yes in app package.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you checked the box in the App's config file to enable Notifications.

Answer (score 2):

The property **settings** of your object **notifier** told you why the toast can't be displayed:

**0**: Enabled, All notifications raised by this app can be displayed.

**1**: DisabledForApplication, The user has disabled notifications for this app.

**2**: DisabledForUser, The user or administrator has disabled all notifications for this user on this computer.

**3**: DisabledByGroupPolicy, An administrator has disabled all notifications on this computer through group policy. The group policy setting overrides the user's setting.

**4**: DisabledByManifest, This app has not declared itself toast capable in its package.appxmanifest file. This setting is found on the manifest's Application UI page, under the Notification section. For an app to send toast, the Toast Capable option must be set to "Yes".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.notificationsetting.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can change directly your Package.appxmanifest from code page :

add ToastCapable to the VisualElements  Tag

```
 <VisualElements  ToastCapable="true">
```

Some times the screen of the Package.appxmanifest dosen't have the option to change it:

[image: my Package.appxmanifest]

Answer (score 1):

Need set small icon for notifications!!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make the application Toast Capable? check this thread: [Toast notification isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738428/toast-notification-isnt-working/14592171#14592171)

Answer (score 0):

An interesting issue I ran into is I was using toast with images.  I had the images in a dependent assembly with copy to output directory.  Scheduling toast just failed silently.  Ondemand toast failed with an HRESULT of E_FAIL (no other information).  When I finally copied the images into the main project (with copy to output directory) then they started working.