# Why Package.Appxmanifest is not found in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, notifications

I am new to Windows Phone 8 development. I wanted to show `Toast notifiation`, and [it is suggested that I need to change in Package.Appxmanifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12814194/744616). I am using C# as language.

I am using `VS2012 Express for Windows Phone`. `WMAppManifest.xml` and `AppManifest.xml` created by Visual Studio wizard,  but I am not able to find `Package.Appxmanifest`.

Please suggest if there any other way to show toast notification.

[image]

Code to display toast:

```
string toast = "This is toast";
ShellToast t = new ShellToast();
t.Title = "Non null";
t.Content = toast;
t.Show();
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that the linked answer is for Windows Store Apps for Windows 8/RT (and not Windows Phone 8); There is good documentation about sending [Toasts for Windows Phone on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Howtosendatoastnotification)

Comment: +1. Thanks. I will go through suggested link.

Comment: @rockstartprogrammer I have edited the answer, now that I see what you are trying to do. You should edit the title of the question, as it doesn't have any relationship with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, now I see you are trying to create and show a [local toast notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207047%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The point is that you can't show toast notifications while the app is in foreground. They can be shown from a [`Background Agent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) while your app is not on the foreground. Your code is ok, but it should be places in a `Background Agent`.

If you still want to show a toast notification within your app, you can do so using the [`ToastPrompt`](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt) control from the [Coding4Fun toolkit](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/):

```
ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt();
toast.Title = "Title";
toast.Message = "message";
toast.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ImageUri", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
toast.Show();
```

---

Your linked post is about **Windows Store** apps.

For **Windows Phone** apps you need to check `ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION` capability in *WMAppManifest.xml* file:

[image]

Comment: After lot of debugging, I kept all Capabilities on. Still problem is same.

Comment: And which is the problem?

Comment: I have first tried to on `ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION `, but doesn't work.

Comment: But what do you mean with "doesn't work". What are you trying to do? What have you done so far?

Comment: Are you aware that normal apps can't randomly display toast notifications. Only background tasks can show toast notifications from code. Push notifications wont be displayed either if your app is active

Comment: @TutanComeOn I have added code, which I am using to display toast.

Comment: @noggin182 Oh I was not knowing this. Can you please suggest link which gives brief about Toast?

Comment: @noggin182 Resolved issue. Should be answer not comment.